# Rust override function argument

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust. And investigating examples. Why does the code outputs 1?
My code:

```
struct S {
    f: fn(),
}

impl S {
    fn f(&self) {
        print!("1");
    }
}


fn main() {
    let f2 = || print!("2");
    let s = S{f: f2};
    s.f(); // prints 1, but I expected 2

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rust distinguishes between methods defined on an `impl` block and fields associated with a struct. There is *no* relationship between the `f` in your `S` struct and the method whose full name is `S::f` which happens to take a `&self` argument.

```
s.f(); // Prints 1
```

This is syntax sugar for

```
S::f(&s); // Prints 1
```

It does *not* look at the fields of an object like Python does. When you have an expression followed by a method call syntax (i.e. a dot, a name, and an open parenthesis), that's always a method call. Method calls resolve statically and are treated as ordinary function calls by the runtime. `s.f()` could also refer to a method defined on a trait somewhere, if it were not defined in your inherent `impl`.

To call a function which happens to be stored in an instance variable, use extra parentheses.

```
(s.f)(); // Prints 2
```

This is *not* a method call. This is a field access, followed by calling the resulting field, which happens to be a function in this case.